# Error trying to run here example on Flutter

Tags: flutter, here-api

So i'm trying to integrate Here to my flutter app. So i was following this page [flutter-sdk-navigate](https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/4.3.0.0/dev_guide/topics/quick-start.html) to get it to work.

I tried to run the hello_map example [4.3.0.0-navigate-flutter](https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/tree/master/examples/4.3.0.0/navigate/flutter/hello_map) but i cannot get it to work.

I did all the steps mentioned (including setting com.here.sdk.access_key_id and com.here.sdk.access_key_secret with my own) but when i run the app i got this on the console and nothing happens.

[image]

I already tried to run a my own example doing the steps mentioned but i got no success either.

[image]

Edit:
I follow the advice and correct all the issues on flutter doctor:

[image]

After that i tried to run the example but got the same error.

Bellow is the output of flutter run -v on the console:

```
[  +17 ms] executing: [/home/rodrigo/Downloads/flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +22 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] 0b8abb4724aa590dd0f429683339b1e045a1594d
[        ] executing: [/home/rodrigo/Downloads/flutter/] git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[   +4 ms] Exit code 0 from: git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[        ] v1.12.13+hotfix.8-0-g0b8abb472
[   +5 ms] executing: [/home/rodrigo/Downloads/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[   +4 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [/home/rodrigo/Downloads/flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[   +4 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[  +39 ms] executing: [/home/rodrigo/Downloads/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[   +5 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] stable
[  +89 ms] executing: /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb devices -l
[   +9 ms] Exit code 0 from: /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb devices -l
[        ] List of devices attached
           emulator-5554          device product:sdk_gphone_x86_arm model:AOSP_on_IA_Emulator device:generic_x86_arm transport_id:1
[  +20 ms] /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell getprop
[  +29 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +36 ms] Found plugin here_sdk at /home/rodrigo/Documentos/plugins/here_sdk/
[ +212 ms] Found plugin here_sdk at /home/rodrigo/Documentos/plugins/here_sdk/
[  +55 ms] Generating /home/rodrigo/Documentos/projects/flutter_here/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
[  +33 ms] ro.hardware = ranchu
[  +26 ms] Using hardware rendering with device AOSP on IA Emulator. If you get graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
[  +14 ms] Launching lib/main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
[   +5 ms] executing: /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/build-tools/29.0.3/aapt dump xmltree /home/rodrigo/Documentos/projects/flutter_here/build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk AndroidManifest.xml
[   +6 ms] Exit code 0 from: /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/build-tools/29.0.3/aapt dump xmltree /home/rodrigo/Documentos/projects/flutter_here/build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk AndroidManifest.xml
[        ] N: android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
             E: manifest (line=2)
               A: android:versionCode(0x0101021b)=(type 0x10)0x1
               A: android:versionName(0x0101021c)="1.0.0" (Raw: "1.0.0")
               A: android:compileSdkVersion(0x01010572)=(type 0x10)0x1c
               A: android:compileSdkVersionCodename(0x01010573)="9" (Raw: "9")
               A: package="com.example.flutter_here" (Raw: "com.example.flutter_here")
               A: platformBuildVersionCode=(type 0x10)0x1c
               A: platformBuildVersionName=(type 0x10)0x9
               E: uses-sdk (line=7)
                 A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0x15
                 A: android:targetSdkVersion(0x01010270)=(type 0x10)0x1d
               E: uses-permission (line=14)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.INTERNET" (Raw: "android.permission.INTERNET")
               E: uses-feature (line=16)
                 A: android:glEsVersion(0x01010281)=(type 0x11)0x20000
               E: uses-permission (line=18)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" (Raw: "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE")
               E: uses-permission (line=19)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" (Raw: "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")
               E: uses-permission (line=20)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" (Raw: "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")
               E: application (line=22)
                 A: android:label(0x01010001)="flutter_here" (Raw: "flutter_here")
                 A: android:icon(0x01010002)=@0x7f080000
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" (Raw: "io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication")
                 A: android:debuggable(0x0101000f)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                 A: android:appComponentFactory(0x0101057a)="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" (Raw: "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory")
                 E: meta-data (line=28)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.here.sdk.access_key_id" (Raw: "com.here.sdk.access_key_id")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)="gi43CjcxO0sNH_4FbU-fgQ" (Raw: "gi43CjcxO0sNH_4FbU-fgQ")
                 E: meta-data (line=31)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.here.sdk.access_key_secret" (Raw: "com.here.sdk.access_key_secret")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)="goEsOTCw2Y0k6Qt1bVdK_UHt5x4AWkpXfqPIBXUSJZp88GPG6FipsoWFa7zQu9kZBdGsfxeUUxk-DOIAU5-tyQ" (Raw: "goEsOTCw2Y0k6Qt1bVdK_UHt5x4AWkpXfqPIBXUSJZp88GPG6FipsoWFa7zQu9kZBdGsfxeUUxk-DOIAU5-tyQ")
                 E: activity (line=35)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x7f0a0000
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.example.flutter_here.MainActivity" (Raw: "com.example.flutter_here.MainActivity")
                   A: android:launchMode(0x0101001d)=(type 0x10)0x1
                   A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0x40003fb4
                   A: android:windowSoftInputMode(0x0101022b)=(type 0x11)0x10
                   A: android:hardwareAccelerated(0x010102d3)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: intent-filter (line=42)
                     E: action (line=43)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.MAIN" (Raw: "android.intent.action.MAIN")
                     E: category (line=45)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" (Raw: "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
                 E: meta-data (line=52)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="flutterEmbedding" (Raw: "flutterEmbedding")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)=(type 0x10)0x2
                 E: provider (line=57)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.here.sdk.engine.InitProvider" (Raw: "com.here.sdk.engine.InitProvider")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                   A: android:authorities(0x01010018)="com.example.flutter_here.com.here.sdk.engine.InitProvider" (Raw: "com.example.flutter_here.com.here.sdk.engine.InitProvider")
[   +5 ms] executing: /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[  +15 ms] Exit code 0 from: /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[        ] --------- beginning of main
           04-30 16:00:42.725 I/GnssLocationProvider( 1951): WakeLock released by handleMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@273242d)
[   +4 ms] executing: /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb version
[        ] executing: /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 logcat -v time -T 04-30 16:00:42.725
[  +17 ms] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
           Version 30.0.0-6374843
           Installed as /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb
[   +2 ms] executing: /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
[  +12 ms] Building APK
[  +13 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[   +1 ms] gradle.properties already sets `android.enableR8`
[   +2 ms] Using gradle from /home/rodrigo/Documentos/projects/flutter_here/android/gradlew.
[   +8 ms] executing: /snap/android-studio/88/android-studio/jre/bin/java -version
[  +47 ms] Exit code 0 from: /snap/android-studio/88/android-studio/jre/bin/java -version
[        ] openjdk version "1.8.0_212-release"
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b4-5784211, mixed mode)
[   +3 ms] executing: [/home/rodrigo/Documentos/projects/flutter_here/android/] /home/rodrigo/Documentos/projects/flutter_here/android/gradlew -Pverbose=true -Ptarget=/home/rodrigo/Documentos/projects/flutter_here/lib/main.dart -Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root -Ptarget-platform=android-x86 assembleDebug
[ +942 ms] > Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:packLibsflutterBuildDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[  +88 ms] > Task :here_sdk:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[        ] > Task :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
[        ] > Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
[        ] > Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[        ] > Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:cleanMergeDebugAssets
[        ] > Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
[ +103 ms] > Task :here_sdk:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:packageDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
[ +191 ms] > Task :app:mergeDebugAssets
[ +102 ms] > Task :app:copyFlutterAssetsDebug
[        ] > Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] > Task :here_sdk:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[  +93 ms] > Task :here_sdk:parseDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] > Task :here_sdk:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:compileDebugKotlin UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:bundleLibCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:compileDebugKotlin UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:bundleLibResDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
[  +97 ms] > Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE
[   +2 ms] > Task :here_sdk:bundleLibRuntimeDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:createFullJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:mergeLibDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:mergeProjectDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:signingConfigWriterDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:mergeDebugNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
[        ] Compatible side by side NDK version was not found.
[        ] > Task :app:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:extractDebugAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:mergeDebugConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:mergeDebugJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:transformNativeLibsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:bundleDebugAar UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
[        ] 60 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 57 up-to-date
[ +327 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 2,0s)
[ +772 ms] calculateSha: LocalDirectory: '/home/rodrigo/Documentos/projects/flutter_here/build/app/outputs/apk'/app.apk
[  +74 ms] calculateSha: reading file took 73us
[ +992 ms] calculateSha: computing sha took 992us
[   +3 ms] ✓ Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
[   +2 ms] executing: /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/build-tools/29.0.3/aapt dump xmltree /home/rodrigo/Documentos/projects/flutter_here/build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk AndroidManifest.xml
[   +9 ms] Exit code 0 from: /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/build-tools/29.0.3/aapt dump xmltree /home/rodrigo/Documentos/projects/flutter_here/build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk AndroidManifest.xml
[        ] N: android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
             E: manifest (line=2)
               A: android:versionCode(0x0101021b)=(type 0x10)0x1
               A: android:versionName(0x0101021c)="1.0.0" (Raw: "1.0.0")
               A: android:compileSdkVersion(0x01010572)=(type 0x10)0x1c
               A: android:compileSdkVersionCodename(0x01010573)="9" (Raw: "9")
               A: package="com.example.flutter_here" (Raw: "com.example.flutter_here")
               A: platformBuildVersionCode=(type 0x10)0x1c
               A: platformBuildVersionName=(type 0x10)0x9
               E: uses-sdk (line=7)
                 A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0x15
                 A: android:targetSdkVersion(0x01010270)=(type 0x10)0x1d
               E: uses-permission (line=14)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.INTERNET" (Raw: "android.permission.INTERNET")
               E: uses-feature (line=16)
                 A: android:glEsVersion(0x01010281)=(type 0x11)0x20000
               E: uses-permission (line=18)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" (Raw: "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE")
               E: uses-permission (line=19)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" (Raw: "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")
               E: uses-permission (line=20)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" (Raw: "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")
               E: application (line=22)
                 A: android:label(0x01010001)="flutter_here" (Raw: "flutter_here")
                 A: android:icon(0x01010002)=@0x7f080000
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" (Raw: "io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication")
                 A: android:debuggable(0x0101000f)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                 A: android:appComponentFactory(0x0101057a)="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" (Raw: "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory")
                 E: meta-data (line=28)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.here.sdk.access_key_id" (Raw: "com.here.sdk.access_key_id")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)="gi43CjcxO0sNH_4FbU-fgQ" (Raw: "gi43CjcxO0sNH_4FbU-fgQ")
                 E: meta-data (line=31)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.here.sdk.access_key_secret" (Raw: "com.here.sdk.access_key_secret")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)="goEsOTCw2Y0k6Qt1bVdK_UHt5x4AWkpXfqPIBXUSJZp88GPG6FipsoWFa7zQu9kZBdGsfxeUUxk-DOIAU5-tyQ" (Raw: "goEsOTCw2Y0k6Qt1bVdK_UHt5x4AWkpXfqPIBXUSJZp88GPG6FipsoWFa7zQu9kZBdGsfxeUUxk-DOIAU5-tyQ")
                 E: activity (line=35)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x7f0a0000
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.example.flutter_here.MainActivity" (Raw: "com.example.flutter_here.MainActivity")
                   A: android:launchMode(0x0101001d)=(type 0x10)0x1
                   A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0x40003fb4
                   A: android:windowSoftInputMode(0x0101022b)=(type 0x11)0x10
                   A: android:hardwareAccelerated(0x010102d3)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: intent-filter (line=42)
                     E: action (line=43)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.MAIN" (Raw: "android.intent.action.MAIN")
                     E: category (line=45)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" (Raw: "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
                 E: meta-data (line=52)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="flutterEmbedding" (Raw: "flutterEmbedding")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)=(type 0x10)0x2
                 E: provider (line=57)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.here.sdk.engine.InitProvider" (Raw: "com.here.sdk.engine.InitProvider")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                   A: android:authorities(0x01010018)="com.example.flutter_here.com.here.sdk.engine.InitProvider" (Raw: "com.example.flutter_here.com.here.sdk.engine.InitProvider")
[   +1 ms] Stopping app 'app.apk' on AOSP on IA Emulator.
[        ] executing: /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell am force-stop com.example.flutter_here
[  +34 ms] executing: /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell pm list packages com.example.flutter_here
[  +28 ms] package:com.example.flutter_here
[   +3 ms] executing: /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell cat /data/local/tmp/sky.com.example.flutter_here.sha1
[  +17 ms] 9ab23403ff0c762c433cd3a7a243744e53f20f38
[        ] Latest build already installed.
[        ] AOSP on IA Emulator startApp
[   +1 ms] executing: /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell am start -a android.intent.action.RUN -f 0x20000000 --ez enable-background-compilation true --ez enable-dart-profiling true --ez enable-checked-mode true --ez verify-entry-points true com.example.flutter_here/com.example.flutter_here.MainActivity
[  +38 ms] Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.RUN flg=0x20000000 cmp=com.example.flutter_here/.MainActivity (has extras) }
[        ] Waiting for observatory port to be available...
[ +209 ms] D/FlutterActivity( 7946): Using the launch theme as normal theme.
[   +1 ms] D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 7946): Setting up FlutterEngine.
[        ] D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 7946): No preferred FlutterEngine was provided. Creating a new FlutterEngine for this FlutterFragment.
[ +121 ms] D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 7946): Attaching FlutterEngine to the Activity that owns this Fragment.
[  +99 ms] D/FlutterView( 7946): Attaching to a FlutterEngine: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@1b88b6d
[        ] D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 7946): Executing Dart entrypoint: main, and sending initial route: /
[ +384 ms] Observatory URL on device: http://127.0.0.1:45099/lkoQI_f1Zyw=/
[   +2 ms] executing: /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 forward tcp:0 tcp:45099
[  +14 ms] 38075
[        ] Forwarded host port 38075 to device port 45099 for Observatory
[  +11 ms] Connecting to service protocol: http://127.0.0.1:38075/lkoQI_f1Zyw=/
[  +74 ms] Fail to connect to service protocol: http://127.0.0.1:38075/lkoQI_f1Zyw=/: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = http://127.0.0.1:38075/lkoQI_f1Zyw=/ws
[   +3 ms] "flutter run" took 5.564ms.
```

Answer (score 2):

update Android Studio.  Go to Android Studio's sdk manager fully install the 29.0.3 if it is partially installed . Or update 29.0.3 . It worked for me

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. I did what you said but it did not solved my problem

Comment: Have you made any android project with android studio? If not then make one and run it. Then again run flutter doctor and check what happens

Comment: I have a lot more projects made on Android Studio. All my projects are on AS to be honest. I really don't think thats a problem with AS, i think the problem is specific with the here sdk. Because if i remove here sdk from the pubspec.yaml the app run just fine. Did you run an example with here sdk? Android or iOS? And what version of Flutter are you using? Thanks again

Comment: My flutter version is same as yours . I ran with Android. Try running this  flutter doctor --android-licenses

Answer (score 0):

1st screenshot says that you lost connection to your device, this does *not* sound related to Flutter or the HERE SDK.

Flutter doctor on the 2nd screenshot indicates that you missed to accept the Android license. When you follow the advised steps from the screenshot, this problem should be gone. Also, it says that no device (or emulator/simulator) is *available at all*. This does not sound like you could run any Flutter app, ... so very strange. I would first try to satisfy the Flutter doctor.

Do you run from command line with "flutter run"? Maybe it's also worth to try from within Android Studio, I could run it on both iOS > 13 simulator and Android emulator without problems. I am using Android Studio 3.5, Flutter v1.15.21-pre.11, on Mac OS X 10.15.2.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Did what you suggested but still couldnt run the example. Edited the post and added some more. Thanks in advance

Comment: Tried to run on the same flutter version as you. But got the same error again

Comment: Looking at the last lines, are you connected to the internet? Otherwise, the HERE SDK will not work and you'll see just a blank screen. You can also contact the HERE support service, they should be able to quickly investigate this issue further.

Comment: Yes, i was connected to the internet all the time. I'm already trying to reach HERE suport,  but for techinical issues HERE tells to look for SO