# Can't run here-maps sdk Flutter example

Tags: here-api

I spend a whole weekend trying to run an example of here sdk with Flutter. Tried on both available versions 4.3.0.0 and 4.3.1.0.

I followed this https://developer.here.com/documentation/flutter-sdk-navigate/4.3.1.0/dev_guide/topics/quick-start.html

Tried with the newer flutter stable version (1.12.13+hotfix.9), tried with the same version of the guide (1.12.13+hotfix.5).

I'm just trying to reach anyone from Here to know if this works for Flutter at all. I know it's beta but i kinda cant go to anywhere at all.

When i try to run the example the app just doesn't run.

I tried a lot on this other post [Error trying to run here example on Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61508637/error-trying-to-run-here-example-on-flutter)

Edit:
The app just don't start. I know it's a here problem because if i remove the here dependencies from the code the app starts normaly

[image]

```
[  +17 ms] executing: [/home/rodrigo/Downloads/flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[  +22 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] 0b8abb4724aa590dd0f429683339b1e045a1594d
[        ] executing: [/home/rodrigo/Downloads/flutter/] git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[   +4 ms] Exit code 0 from: git describe --match v*.*.* --first-parent --long --tags
[        ] v1.12.13+hotfix.8-0-g0b8abb472
[   +5 ms] executing: [/home/rodrigo/Downloads/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[   +4 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [/home/rodrigo/Downloads/flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[   +4 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[  +39 ms] executing: [/home/rodrigo/Downloads/flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[   +5 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] stable
[  +89 ms] executing: /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb devices -l
[   +9 ms] Exit code 0 from: /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb devices -l
[        ] List of devices attached
           emulator-5554          device product:sdk_gphone_x86_arm model:AOSP_on_IA_Emulator device:generic_x86_arm transport_id:1
[  +20 ms] /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell getprop
[  +29 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidMavenArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +36 ms] Found plugin here_sdk at /home/rodrigo/Documentos/plugins/here_sdk/
[ +212 ms] Found plugin here_sdk at /home/rodrigo/Documentos/plugins/here_sdk/
[  +55 ms] Generating /home/rodrigo/Documentos/projects/flutter_here/android/app/src/main/java/io/flutter/plugins/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java
[  +33 ms] ro.hardware = ranchu
[  +26 ms] Using hardware rendering with device AOSP on IA Emulator. If you get graphics artifacts, consider enabling software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
[  +14 ms] Launching lib/main.dart on AOSP on IA Emulator in debug mode...
[   +5 ms] executing: /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/build-tools/29.0.3/aapt dump xmltree /home/rodrigo/Documentos/projects/flutter_here/build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk AndroidManifest.xml
[   +6 ms] Exit code 0 from: /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/build-tools/29.0.3/aapt dump xmltree /home/rodrigo/Documentos/projects/flutter_here/build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk AndroidManifest.xml
[        ] N: android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
             E: manifest (line=2)
               A: android:versionCode(0x0101021b)=(type 0x10)0x1
               A: android:versionName(0x0101021c)="1.0.0" (Raw: "1.0.0")
               A: android:compileSdkVersion(0x01010572)=(type 0x10)0x1c
               A: android:compileSdkVersionCodename(0x01010573)="9" (Raw: "9")
               A: package="com.example.flutter_here" (Raw: "com.example.flutter_here")
               A: platformBuildVersionCode=(type 0x10)0x1c
               A: platformBuildVersionName=(type 0x10)0x9
               E: uses-sdk (line=7)
                 A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0x15
                 A: android:targetSdkVersion(0x01010270)=(type 0x10)0x1d
               E: uses-permission (line=14)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.INTERNET" (Raw: "android.permission.INTERNET")
               E: uses-feature (line=16)
                 A: android:glEsVersion(0x01010281)=(type 0x11)0x20000
               E: uses-permission (line=18)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" (Raw: "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE")
               E: uses-permission (line=19)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" (Raw: "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")
               E: uses-permission (line=20)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" (Raw: "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")
               E: application (line=22)
                 A: android:label(0x01010001)="flutter_here" (Raw: "flutter_here")
                 A: android:icon(0x01010002)=@0x7f080000
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" (Raw: "io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication")
                 A: android:debuggable(0x0101000f)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                 A: android:appComponentFactory(0x0101057a)="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" (Raw: "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory")
                 E: meta-data (line=28)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.here.sdk.access_key_id" (Raw: "com.here.sdk.access_key_id")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)="gi43CjcxO0sNH_4FbU-fgQ" (Raw: "gi43CjcxO0sNH_4FbU-fgQ")
                 E: meta-data (line=31)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.here.sdk.access_key_secret" (Raw: "com.here.sdk.access_key_secret")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)="goEsOTCw2Y0k6Qt1bVdK_UHt5x4AWkpXfqPIBXUSJZp88GPG6FipsoWFa7zQu9kZBdGsfxeUUxk-DOIAU5-tyQ" (Raw: "goEsOTCw2Y0k6Qt1bVdK_UHt5x4AWkpXfqPIBXUSJZp88GPG6FipsoWFa7zQu9kZBdGsfxeUUxk-DOIAU5-tyQ")
                 E: activity (line=35)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x7f0a0000
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.example.flutter_here.MainActivity" (Raw: "com.example.flutter_here.MainActivity")
                   A: android:launchMode(0x0101001d)=(type 0x10)0x1
                   A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0x40003fb4
                   A: android:windowSoftInputMode(0x0101022b)=(type 0x11)0x10
                   A: android:hardwareAccelerated(0x010102d3)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: intent-filter (line=42)
                     E: action (line=43)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.MAIN" (Raw: "android.intent.action.MAIN")
                     E: category (line=45)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" (Raw: "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
                 E: meta-data (line=52)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="flutterEmbedding" (Raw: "flutterEmbedding")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)=(type 0x10)0x2
                 E: provider (line=57)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.here.sdk.engine.InitProvider" (Raw: "com.here.sdk.engine.InitProvider")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                   A: android:authorities(0x01010018)="com.example.flutter_here.com.here.sdk.engine.InitProvider" (Raw: "com.example.flutter_here.com.here.sdk.engine.InitProvider")
[   +5 ms] executing: /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[  +15 ms] Exit code 0 from: /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell -x logcat -v time -t 1
[        ] --------- beginning of main
           04-30 16:00:42.725 I/GnssLocationProvider( 1951): WakeLock released by handleMessage(REPORT_SV_STATUS, 0, com.android.server.location.GnssLocationProvider$SvStatusInfo@273242d)
[   +4 ms] executing: /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb version
[        ] executing: /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 logcat -v time -T 04-30 16:00:42.725
[  +17 ms] Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.41
           Version 30.0.0-6374843
           Installed as /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb
[   +2 ms] executing: /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb start-server
[  +12 ms] Building APK
[  +13 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
[   +1 ms] gradle.properties already sets `android.enableR8`
[   +2 ms] Using gradle from /home/rodrigo/Documentos/projects/flutter_here/android/gradlew.
[   +8 ms] executing: /snap/android-studio/88/android-studio/jre/bin/java -version
[  +47 ms] Exit code 0 from: /snap/android-studio/88/android-studio/jre/bin/java -version
[        ] openjdk version "1.8.0_212-release"
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_212-release-1586-b4-5784211)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.212-b4-5784211, mixed mode)
[   +3 ms] executing: [/home/rodrigo/Documentos/projects/flutter_here/android/] /home/rodrigo/Documentos/projects/flutter_here/android/gradlew -Pverbose=true -Ptarget=/home/rodrigo/Documentos/projects/flutter_here/lib/main.dart -Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Pfilesystem-scheme=org-dartlang-root -Ptarget-platform=android-x86 assembleDebug
[ +942 ms] > Task :app:compileFlutterBuildDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:packLibsflutterBuildDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
[  +88 ms] > Task :here_sdk:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[        ] > Task :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
[        ] > Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
[        ] > Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[        ] > Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:cleanMergeDebugAssets
[        ] > Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
[ +103 ms] > Task :here_sdk:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:packageDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
[ +191 ms] > Task :app:mergeDebugAssets
[ +102 ms] > Task :app:copyFlutterAssetsDebug
[        ] > Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] > Task :here_sdk:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
[  +93 ms] > Task :here_sdk:parseDebugLibraryResources UP-TO-DATE
[   +1 ms] > Task :here_sdk:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:compileDebugKotlin UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:bundleLibCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:compileDebugKotlin UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:bundleLibResDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:mergeDebugJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
[  +97 ms] > Task :app:desugarDebugFileDependencies UP-TO-DATE
[   +2 ms] > Task :here_sdk:bundleLibRuntimeDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:createFullJarDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:mergeExtDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:mergeLibDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:mergeProjectDexDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:signingConfigWriterDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:mergeDebugNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:mergeDebugNativeLibs UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:stripDebugDebugSymbols UP-TO-DATE
[        ] Compatible side by side NDK version was not found.
[        ] > Task :app:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :app:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:extractDebugAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:mergeDebugGeneratedProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:mergeDebugConsumerProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:prepareLintJarForPublish UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:mergeDebugJavaResource UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:transformNativeLibsWithSyncJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:bundleDebugAar UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
[        ] > Task :here_sdk:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
[        ] BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
[        ] 60 actionable tasks: 3 executed, 57 up-to-date
[ +327 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... (completed in 2,0s)
[ +772 ms] calculateSha: LocalDirectory: '/home/rodrigo/Documentos/projects/flutter_here/build/app/outputs/apk'/app.apk
[  +74 ms] calculateSha: reading file took 73us
[ +992 ms] calculateSha: computing sha took 992us
[   +3 ms] ✓ Built build/app/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk.
[   +2 ms] executing: /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/build-tools/29.0.3/aapt dump xmltree /home/rodrigo/Documentos/projects/flutter_here/build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk AndroidManifest.xml
[   +9 ms] Exit code 0 from: /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/build-tools/29.0.3/aapt dump xmltree /home/rodrigo/Documentos/projects/flutter_here/build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk AndroidManifest.xml
[        ] N: android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
             E: manifest (line=2)
               A: android:versionCode(0x0101021b)=(type 0x10)0x1
               A: android:versionName(0x0101021c)="1.0.0" (Raw: "1.0.0")
               A: android:compileSdkVersion(0x01010572)=(type 0x10)0x1c
               A: android:compileSdkVersionCodename(0x01010573)="9" (Raw: "9")
               A: package="com.example.flutter_here" (Raw: "com.example.flutter_here")
               A: platformBuildVersionCode=(type 0x10)0x1c
               A: platformBuildVersionName=(type 0x10)0x9
               E: uses-sdk (line=7)
                 A: android:minSdkVersion(0x0101020c)=(type 0x10)0x15
                 A: android:targetSdkVersion(0x01010270)=(type 0x10)0x1d
               E: uses-permission (line=14)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.INTERNET" (Raw: "android.permission.INTERNET")
               E: uses-feature (line=16)
                 A: android:glEsVersion(0x01010281)=(type 0x11)0x20000
               E: uses-permission (line=18)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" (Raw: "android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE")
               E: uses-permission (line=19)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" (Raw: "android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")
               E: uses-permission (line=20)
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" (Raw: "android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE")
               E: application (line=22)
                 A: android:label(0x01010001)="flutter_here" (Raw: "flutter_here")
                 A: android:icon(0x01010002)=@0x7f080000
                 A: android:name(0x01010003)="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" (Raw: "io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication")
                 A: android:debuggable(0x0101000f)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                 A: android:appComponentFactory(0x0101057a)="androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory" (Raw: "androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory")
                 E: meta-data (line=28)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.here.sdk.access_key_id" (Raw: "com.here.sdk.access_key_id")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)="gi43CjcxO0sNH_4FbU-fgQ" (Raw: "gi43CjcxO0sNH_4FbU-fgQ")
                 E: meta-data (line=31)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.here.sdk.access_key_secret" (Raw: "com.here.sdk.access_key_secret")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)="goEsOTCw2Y0k6Qt1bVdK_UHt5x4AWkpXfqPIBXUSJZp88GPG6FipsoWFa7zQu9kZBdGsfxeUUxk-DOIAU5-tyQ" (Raw: "goEsOTCw2Y0k6Qt1bVdK_UHt5x4AWkpXfqPIBXUSJZp88GPG6FipsoWFa7zQu9kZBdGsfxeUUxk-DOIAU5-tyQ")
                 E: activity (line=35)
                   A: android:theme(0x01010000)=@0x7f0a0000
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.example.flutter_here.MainActivity" (Raw: "com.example.flutter_here.MainActivity")
                   A: android:launchMode(0x0101001d)=(type 0x10)0x1
                   A: android:configChanges(0x0101001f)=(type 0x11)0x40003fb4
                   A: android:windowSoftInputMode(0x0101022b)=(type 0x11)0x10
                   A: android:hardwareAccelerated(0x010102d3)=(type 0x12)0xffffffff
                   E: intent-filter (line=42)
                     E: action (line=43)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.action.MAIN" (Raw: "android.intent.action.MAIN")
                     E: category (line=45)
                       A: android:name(0x01010003)="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" (Raw: "android.intent.category.LAUNCHER")
                 E: meta-data (line=52)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="flutterEmbedding" (Raw: "flutterEmbedding")
                   A: android:value(0x01010024)=(type 0x10)0x2
                 E: provider (line=57)
                   A: android:name(0x01010003)="com.here.sdk.engine.InitProvider" (Raw: "com.here.sdk.engine.InitProvider")
                   A: android:exported(0x01010010)=(type 0x12)0x0
                   A: android:authorities(0x01010018)="com.example.flutter_here.com.here.sdk.engine.InitProvider" (Raw: "com.example.flutter_here.com.here.sdk.engine.InitProvider")
[   +1 ms] Stopping app 'app.apk' on AOSP on IA Emulator.
[        ] executing: /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell am force-stop com.example.flutter_here
[  +34 ms] executing: /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell pm list packages com.example.flutter_here
[  +28 ms] package:com.example.flutter_here
[   +3 ms] executing: /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell cat /data/local/tmp/sky.com.example.flutter_here.sha1
[  +17 ms] 9ab23403ff0c762c433cd3a7a243744e53f20f38
[        ] Latest build already installed.
[        ] AOSP on IA Emulator startApp
[   +1 ms] executing: /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 shell am start -a android.intent.action.RUN -f 0x20000000 --ez enable-background-compilation true --ez enable-dart-profiling true --ez enable-checked-mode true --ez verify-entry-points true com.example.flutter_here/com.example.flutter_here.MainActivity
[  +38 ms] Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.RUN flg=0x20000000 cmp=com.example.flutter_here/.MainActivity (has extras) }
[        ] Waiting for observatory port to be available...
[ +209 ms] D/FlutterActivity( 7946): Using the launch theme as normal theme.
[   +1 ms] D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 7946): Setting up FlutterEngine.
[        ] D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 7946): No preferred FlutterEngine was provided. Creating a new FlutterEngine for this FlutterFragment.
[ +121 ms] D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 7946): Attaching FlutterEngine to the Activity that owns this Fragment.
[  +99 ms] D/FlutterView( 7946): Attaching to a FlutterEngine: io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine@1b88b6d
[        ] D/FlutterActivityAndFragmentDelegate( 7946): Executing Dart entrypoint: main, and sending initial route: /
[ +384 ms] Observatory URL on device: http://127.0.0.1:45099/lkoQI_f1Zyw=/
[   +2 ms] executing: /home/rodrigo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s emulator-5554 forward tcp:0 tcp:45099
[  +14 ms] 38075
[        ] Forwarded host port 38075 to device port 45099 for Observatory
[  +11 ms] Connecting to service protocol: http://127.0.0.1:38075/lkoQI_f1Zyw=/
[  +74 ms] Fail to connect to service protocol: http://127.0.0.1:38075/lkoQI_f1Zyw=/: HttpException: Connection closed before full header was received, uri = http://127.0.0.1:38075/lkoQI_f1Zyw=/ws
[   +3 ms] "flutter run" took 5.564ms.
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try switching to flutter beta channel? I had some major issues with Flutter 1.12 (stable) as well that went away when I switched to 1.17 (beta)

```
$ flutter channel beta
$ flutter upgrade
$ flutter clean
```

You can always go back to stable with:

```
$ flutter channel stable
$ flutter upgrade
$ flutter clean
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for helping. Tried with the 1.17.0-3.4.pre flutter version and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

For me the demo application from Github (https://github.com/heremaps/here-sdk-examples/tree/master/examples/latest/explore/flutter/hello_map) and another application I created myself based on the demo application were both building and running fine on iOS Device and on Android Simulator with the following settings:

- Flutter (Channel beta, v1.17.0)
- Android Emulator with Pixel 3 API 29 (6GB disc, 512mb SD, rest default)

Note 1: On Android Emulator I noticed some map rendering issues, which seem caused by Emulator.
Note 2: Running it on iOS Simulator requires the latest Mac OS, therefore I was not able to test this.

I recommend you try it again after upgrading to Flutter Beta with the GitHub Hello-World sample app on a real device (as issue might be caused 
by our Android Emulator)

Update:
Also ensure to follow the documentation. E.g. the plugin is using Platform Views which require your application to opt-in as this Flutter feature is still beta (at least on iOS). E.g. remember to set io.flutter.embedded_views_preview = YES in your info.plist file.